# semantic ui autocomplete with get request doesnt work

Tags: html, node.js, express, mongoose, semantic-ui

I am trying to make an autocompleting search bar. What I have until now is:

```
  <div class="ui search">
    <div class="ui inverted transparent icon input">
      <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>





<script>
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    apiSettings: {
      url: '/search?key={query}'
    },
  });
</script>
```

And router.get('/search',... 
This one does a database search (mongoose) and returns an array with all the documents which name contains the search string and does: res.send(thearray). But this doesn't work, is it right to use res.send and is the script right?

Comment: What autocomplete plugin are you using? What input is it expecting from the API? Does your API support the requests sent by that plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Please see examples in Semantic UI: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/examples

```
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    apiSettings: {
      url: '//api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}'
    },
    fields: {
      results : 'items',
      title   : 'name',
      url     : 'html_url'
    },
    minCharacters : 3
  })
;
```

You need to map the response from your API into the matching fields required for search.